# How to call a stored routine/function from Spring/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, stored-functions

Is there a possibility to call a stored function (MySql Server) via Spring/Hibernate?

The function gets two parameter (int, varchar(20)) and returns a varchar(255),
I think there must me a possibility with named-query but I have no idea how to generate the mapping.

Comment: Did you meant "Hibernate" instead of "NHibernate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to wrap the stored procedure in another stored procedure that returns a resultset.

See [Hibernate Core Reference Chapter 18](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#sp_query) for info on named queries and calling stored procedures.